# Jackson XML - deserializing XML with namespace prefixes

Tags: java, xml, jackson

I'm working with the Jackson XML plugin (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml), and I'm not sure if it's supported, but I'm wondering if it's possible to both serialize and deserialize XML with namespace prefixes, like so:

```
<name:Foo>
  <name:Bar>
    <name:x>x</name:x>
    <name:y>y</name:y>
  </name:Bar>
</name:Foo>
```

I can generate this type of XML using Jackson's plugin like so:

```
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName="name:Bar")
public Bar getBar() {
    return bar;
}
```

However, I can't find a way to configure my POJOs to deserialize from the XML generated. Please see the following example code:

```
public class Bar{
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="name:x")
    public String x = "x";
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="name:y")
    public String y = "y";
}
```

---

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName="name:Foo")
    public class Foo{
        private Bar bar;

        @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="name:Bar")
        public Bar getBar() {
           return bar;
        }

        public void setBar(Bar bar) {
            this.bar = bar;
        }   
}
```

---

```
public class TestDeserialization {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.setBar(new Bar());

        XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
        String xml = xmlMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(foo);
        System.out.println(xml);
        System.out.println("XML Desearialzing....");
        Foo foo2= xmlMapper.readValue(xml, Foo.class);
        System.out.println(xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(foo2));
     }
}
```

Trying to run this test gives me an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Undeclared namespace prefix "name"
```

which is understandable, but I was wondering if there's a way to get this to work with Jackson XML?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`JacksonXmlProperty` annotation has property `namespace`. Use it for defining `namespace`

```
public class Bar {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(namespace = "name",localName="x")
    public String x = "x";
    @JacksonXmlProperty(namespace = "name",localName="y")
    public String y = "y";
} 

@JacksonXmlRootElement(namespace = "name", localName = "Foo")
public class Foo {
   private Bar bar;

   @JacksonXmlProperty(namespace = "name", localName = "Bar")
   public Bar getBar() {
      return bar;
   }

   public void setBar(Bar bar) {
      this.bar = bar;
   }
}
```

Comment: Using the namespace configuration like above generates the following XML: `<Foo xmlns="name">
  <Bar>
    <x>x</x>
    <y>y</y>
  </Bar>
</Foo>` - Can I assume this is synonymous with the sample XML I gave before?

Comment: @jtyler yes, this xml is similar to yours

Comment: @Ilya: I am facing the same issue as in this question. I am also getting `<Foo xmlns="name"> <Bar> <x>x</x> <y>y</y> </Bar> </Foo>`. How is this same as `<name:foo></name:foo>` ?? The prefix is not getting added. Can you elaborate ?

Comment: @SiddharthTrikha my understanding is either you use xmlns directly with a name as you stated <Foo xmlns="name"> which means the Foo tag is defined in the "name" namespace, or you give an alias to this namespace and use it like <mynamespace:Foo xmlns:mynamespace="name">

Answer (score 5):

Though this is an old post, I just ran into this issue and the only solution to match the XML required for my service calls was something like this, where the namespace declaration also uses the prefix.

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "entry")
abstract class BaseEntry implements Serializable { 
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6835429382441010779L;
    private final String xmlns = "com.foo.bar"; 
    private String type;
    
    protected BaseEntry(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "xmlns:ns2", isAttribute = true)
    public String getXmlns() {
        return xmlns;
    }
}
```

This produces something like:

```
<entry type="com.foo.bar" xmlns:ns2="com.foo.bar">
...
</entry>
```

Answer (score 1):

Configuring the `xmlMapper` to ignore the namespace could avoid this exception.

```java
XMLInputFactory input = new WstxInputFactory();
input.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_NAMESPACE_AWARE, Boolean.FALSE);
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper(new XmlFactory(input, new WstxOutputFactory()));
```

Comes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39343366/6483409).