# XML deserialization using jackson-dataformat-xml custom root element?

Tags: json, xml, jaxb, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

So I am using Jackson for **JSON serialization/deserialization** succesfully uptil now, now I am also trying to use it for **XML serialization/deserialization** using it's `jackson-dataformat-xml-2.3.0.jar`.

I have used

`objectmapper.reader(Student.class).withRootName("prefix:student").readValue(jsonString)`

to deserialize my JSON (having root name with prefix) to `Student` class which worked succesfully.

Now, I am trying to deserialize my XML string (having root name with prefix) to `Student` :

**XML:**

```
<prefix:student>
  <name>
    Jack Jones
  </name>
  <id>1</id>
</prefix:student>
```

**My POJO:**

```
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "name",
        "id",
        ....
    })
    @XmlRootElement(name = "student")
    public class Student
    {

        protected String name;
        BigInteger id;  
..........................
    }
```

I was desrializing this using `XmlMapper` in `jackson-dataformat-xml` like this:

```
xmlMapper.reader(Student.class).withRootName("prefix:student").readValue(xmlString)
```

I get the following exception:

```
java.io.IOException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Undeclared namespace prefix "prefix"
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,9]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.util.StaxUtil.throwXmlAsIOException(StaxUtil.java:24)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlFactory._createParser(XmlFactory.java:473)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlFactory._createParser(XmlFactory.java:26)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.createParser(JsonFactory.java:844)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2091)

Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Undeclared namespace prefix "prefix"
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,9]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.constructWfcException(StreamScanner.java:606)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwParseError(StreamScanner.java:479)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.InputElementStack.resolveAndValidateElement(InputElementStack.java:507)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleStartElem(BasicStreamReader.java:2977)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleRootElem(BasicStreamReader.java:2098)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2078)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1134)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlFactory._initializeXmlReader(XmlFactory.java:581)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlFactory._createParser(XmlFactory.java:471)
    ... 6 more
```

What do I need to do for XML deserialization with custom root name ??

Comment: Your root element name isn't `student`, like defined here: `@XmlRootElement(name = "student")`!

Comment: @My-Name-Is: I have edited the question. Basically I have a namespace prefix inside root name. So root name `student` becomes `prefix:student`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that XML input is invalid as it is missing the namespace declaration for `prefix`: if namespace handling is enabled (as it is by most modern XML parsers), Jackson XML module can't do anything about that.

But as per other answer it is often possible to configure underlying XML parser to disable namespace handling, in which case the whole element name is just considered part of "local name", and no namespace information will be maintained.

Just make sure to use either `Woodstox` or `Aalto` Stax parsers: one in JDK does not support no-namespace mode, I think.

Comment: I have got the same issue, I have serialized class with `JacksonXmlModule` and `XmlMapper`, with ` @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "namespaceprefix:localname" ) ` is there any way I can add namespace prefix with the local name, so that I will not get `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Undeclared namespace prefix` with Jackson XML module now!.

Answer (score 6):

Try to configure your XmlMapper to ignore namespaces :

```
XMLInputFactory input = new WstxInputFactory();
input.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_NAMESPACE_AWARE, Boolean.FALSE);
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper(new XmlFactory(input, new WstxOutputFactory()));
```

Also, you might have to change your 
`@XmlRootElement(name= "student")` 
to 
`@XmlRootElement(name= "prefix:student")`

Edit :

As StaxMan said, your problem come from the fact that you use a prefix that has not been declared.

This can be deduced by the log you gave us (Line 1 and line 9 => Undeclared namespace prefix "prefix").

I was under the impression that you could not modify your XML String.

But if you can, StaxMan solution is cleaner and you should add the namespace declaration instead of disabling your parser namespace validation :

```
<prefix:student xmlns:prefix="http://www.somenamespace.org">
  <name>
    Jack Jones
  </name>
  <id>1</id>
</prefix:student>
```