# How to add namespace and prefix in xml response from Spring Boot Rest Api

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, rest

My target is to get xml response from my rest api controller like below-

```
<RegisterUser xmlns:idtp="http://example.com">
   <Head ver="1.0" ts="12/1/2020 2:15:18 AM" orgId="ABL" msgId="1"/>
   <Req id="2b4251e7-4275-40c4-b366-5da09f10fd47" note="RegisterUser" ts="12/1/2020 
     2:15:18 AM" type="RegisterUser"/>
   <Entity seqNum="1">
      <Info>
         <EntityType>Individual</EntityType >
         <Name>Sample User 1</Name >
      </Info>
   </Entity>
</RegisterUser>
```

Below is my RegisterUser class-

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlRootElement;

@JacksonXmlRootElement(namespace="http://www.aa.com/bb")

public class RegisterUser {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Head")
    private Head head;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Req")
    private Req req;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Entity")
    private Entity entity;

    public Head getHead() {
        return head;
    }
    public void setHead(Head head) {
        this.head = head;
    }
    public Req getReq() {
        return req;
    }
    public void setReq(Req req) {
        this.req = req;
    }
    public Entity getEntity() {
        return entity;
    }
    public void setEntity(Entity entity) {
        this.entity = entity;
    }
    
}
```

Here is Controller method-

```
@PostMapping(value="/", produces= MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, consumes= 
   {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.TEXT_XML_VALUE})
public RegisterUser registerUser(@RequestBody RegisterUser userReg){
    RegisterUser registerUser = new RegisterUser();
    registerUser.setHead(userReg.getHead());
    registerUser.setReq(userReg.getReq());
    registerUser.setEntity(userReg.getEntity());
    return registerUser;
}
```

Here is my dependency-

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I am getting below xml response-

```
<RegisterUser xmlns ="http://example.com">
    <Head xmlns="" ver="1.0" ts="12/1/2020 2:15:18 AM" orgId="ABL" msgId="1"/>
    <Req xmlns="" id="2b4251e7-4275-40c4-b366-5da09f10fd47" note="RegisterUser" 
      ts="12/1/2020 2:15:18 AM" type="RegisterUser"/>
    <Entity xmlns="" seqNum="1">
       <Info>
         <EntityType>Individual</EntityType >
         <Name>Sample User 1</Name >
       </Info>
    </Entity>
</RegisterUser>
```

Can anyone please give me any idea how I can get `xmlns:idtp` instead of `xmlns` in RegisterUser  element and remove all other `xmlns` from Head, Req and Entity elements.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16442805/jackson-xml-deserializing-xml-with-namespace-prefixes